# How to hide bones in animation

Tags: animation, bones

How does one put a keyframe for a bone(and the part of the mesh assigned to it) to appear/disappear?
If it was another object one could keyframe the visibility buttons but it is a part of a mesh, f.e. a weapon.

Comment: You want to animate the visibility of a vertex group?

Comment: Rather want to make vertex groups appear and disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a bone for this, but you can use the associated vertex group with a mask modifier.
1st add a Mask modifier to your mesh.
[image: mask modifier]

Then choose the vertex group in the list
[image: choose VGroup]

Invert the mask with the double arrow button
[image: invert]

You can animate the renderability by keyframing the "renderable" (camera) button (and viewport visibility with the eye icon)
[image: animate]

The mask modifier doesn't use precise weights, it's just yes/no so if a vertice has 0.01 weight, it will be completely hidden.

Comment: Thanks, I've read about this before though not as good explained. I improvised keyframing the bones at z: 1000 :D but the mask method would be better. Btw I really appreciate the work you did by making all of these screenshots and writing the clear instructions, bless you!

Comment: @Jonathan Glad to help :) and thanks for your kindness : I really appreciate too!